# Домра или домбра?

Tags: орфография, этимология

Как правильно: "домра" или "домбра"? Или два разных инструмента? И что это слово означает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Домра и домбра  - это похожие, но все-таки разные музыкальные инструменты. Это струнные инструменты с узким грифом.
Но  у домбры  две струны, а  у домры - три и даже четыре.
Домра напоминает маленькую игрушку, а домбра достигает в длину больше метра. 
И принадлежат они разным культурам:домбра - инструмент казахский, а домра - инструмент русский.

Answer (score 1):

Домра и домбра - разные музыкальные инструменты с овальным корпусом. В казахском языке национальный инструмент пишется "домбыра".